# How to import a file using apiary?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I want to browse a file from my system and want import it using apiray so how I can do that please help me into this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use Apiary CLI (https://help.apiary.io/tools/apiary-cli/)

The Apiary CLI gem is a command line tool for developing and previewing API Blueprint documents locally. It can also be used for pushing updated documents to and fetching existing documents from Apiary.io.

Comment: I am having post call. and I want to import the file using that post call.is any way to do that?